# Using OpenSSL C library Envelope routines for public key encryption, saving output in a common standard

Tags: public-key, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL's EVP routines (EVP_SealInit, EVP_SealUpdate, EVP_SealFinal) for public key encryption in my application.  It works perfect for the app's internal data structures, however at some point I want to save the encrypted message in a standalone file.  I'd rather save in a common format that can be opened using at the minimum openssl's command line utilities.

I don't see any command line functions that match the C library EVP_Seal functions, just ones for handling raw RSA and AES encryption (where you'd have to extract the components out of the file manually as a first step), or ones that handle S/MIME.

Is there a C API for converting the output of SealUpdate() / SealFinal() to one of the S/MIME formats?  Or would I have to go through the RFCs and do this manually?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question doesn’t meet a Cryptography Stack Exchange guideline.

Comment: `CMS_encrypt` for CMS, or combined with `SMIME_write_CMS` for SMIME. But this is not a question about cryptography. How 'common' CMS/PKCS7 and SMIME really are _could_ be about crypto, but would be opinion-based, which is also out of scope. They definitely are standard.